# Convert videos into images specifying frame per seconds with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a 19 seconds of video and i want to extract frame at 30 frame per seconds. So I checked on the net how to do it but I am thinking that the results are inaccurate.

```
ffmpeg -i "the video.mp4" -vf fps=30 frames/frame_%04d.png -hide_banner
```

"the video.mp4" is 19 seconds in lenght so 30 * 19 = 570 but executing the command above results into 584 frames which should be 570 frames.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that i was having the length incorrectly.

```
ffprobe -i "the video.mp4" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"
```

results into 19.458333 * 30 = 583.74999